# SQLite3 Limiting Inner Join Using Time

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, inner-join

I am trying to use SQLite3 to form correlations between two tables that have similar data.
Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE a (date TEXT, user TEXT, ip TEXT);
CREATE INDEX a_index ON a (date, user, ip);
CREATE TABLE b (date TEXT, ip TEXT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX b_index ON b (date, ip);

INSERT INTO a VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:16', 'a', '127.0.0.1');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:18', 'b', '127.0.0.2');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:21', 'c', '127.0.0.3');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:21', 'd', '127.0.0.4');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:29', 'e', '127.0.0.5');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2014-03-01 03:16:32', 'f', '127.0.0.6');

INSERT INTO b VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:16', '127.0.0.1');
INSERT INTO b VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:17', '127.0.0.1');
INSERT INTO b VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:19', '127.0.0.1');
INSERT INTO b VALUES('2014-03-01 03:15:22', '127.0.0.4');
INSERT INTO b VALUES('2014-03-01 03:16:32', '127.0.0.5');
```

I know I could simply use an inner join to combine these two sets, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.ip = b.ip AND a.date = b.date;
```

and it would return

```
2014-03-01 03:15:16|a|127.0.0.1|2014-03-01 03:15:16|127.0.0.1
```

as expected. However, due to clock drift in time recording. I would like to match any possible entries +- 3 seconds from each other. In this case, I have used:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.ip = b.ip AND a.date BETWEEN DATETIME(b.date, '-3 seconds') AND DATETIME(b.date, '+3 seconds');
```

This works, although it's returning more entries than I wanted. Instead of the following:

```
2014-03-01 03:15:16|a|127.0.0.1|2014-03-01 03:15:16|127.0.0.1
2014-03-01 03:15:16|a|127.0.0.1|2014-03-01 03:15:17|127.0.0.1
2014-03-01 03:15:16|a|127.0.0.1|2014-03-01 03:15:19|127.0.0.1
2014-03-01 03:15:21|d|127.0.0.4|2014-03-01 03:15:22|127.0.0.4
```

I am wondering if it's possible to return only one entry max per entry in the a table if a matching entry is found in the b table. So the expected result would look something like this:

```
2014-03-01 03:15:16|a|127.0.0.1|2014-03-01 03:15:16|127.0.0.1
2014-03-01 03:15:21|d|127.0.0.4|2014-03-01 03:15:22|127.0.0.4
```

How should / could this be accomplished?

Comment: well the resultset you get seems to be correct. What is your logic that you select the `2014-03-01 03:15:16` and not `2014-03-01 03:15:18` for `127.0.0.1` ip?

Comment: Good question, but I was actually picking the first entry that comes up, similar to LIMIT 1 in SQL. Supposedly, I would want the time that's closest to the one in the 'a' table.

Comment: What should happen when there are multiple possible matches in both tables?

Comment: So essentially what I am looking for is similar to the following logic: a) Loop through table A's entries; b) See if there is a corresponding entry in table B that has the same IP with a timestamp that's += 3 seconds; c) If one entry exists, print that entry. If multiple entries exist, choose the one that has the closet time to the one in table A and print that; d) Continue with the next entry in table A.

Comment: Explicitly `SELECT` the fields you want, leave out the 2nd timestamp (which you don't appear to be interested in anyway) that's making the “duplicate” rows different, and use `SELECT DISTINCT` so that you only get unique rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment, above (“Explicitly SELECT the fields you want, leave out the 2nd timestamp (which you don't appear to be interested in anyway) that's making the “duplicate” rows different, and use SELECT DISTINCT so that you only get unique rows.”), you could try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.date, a.user, a.ip 
  FROM a JOIN b ON a.ip = b.ip 
  AND a.date 
    BETWEEN DATETIME(b.date, '-3 seconds')
      AND DATETIME(b.date, '+3 seconds');
```

Comment: Interesting approach, will take a look at this and see if it will work for what I am doing, thanks!